# I have a list of checkboxes where i have to add using java code (not xml ) a new button with text "Submit" when user select any check box

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have a list of checkboxes where i have to add using java code (not xml ) a new button with text "Submit" when user select any check box

```
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    CheckBox txtListChild = (CheckBox) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams firstParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 150);
    //Button h = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button999) ;
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int color = Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255);
    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    txtListChild.setLayoutParams(firstParam);
    txtListChild.setBackgroundColor(color);
    txtListChild.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
            if(arg1)
                linearLayout.addView(addButton());
        }
    } 
   return convertView;
}

private Button addButton(){
    Button btnToBeAdded = new Button(getContext());
    btnToBeAdded.setText("YourText");
    btnToBeAdded.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    btnToBeAdded.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    btnToBeAdded.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    btnToBeAdded.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //perform button click
        }
    });
    return btnToBeAdded;
}
```

Layout Xml is where i have tried with button visibility and the button visibility is not working as of nows

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New CheckBox"
            android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

My activity file is as below

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_list);

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                + " : "
                                + listDataChild.get(
                                listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return false;
            }
        });
        // Listview Group expanded listener
        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

Comment: try to change VISIBILITY.

Comment: how can i add dynamically the submit button , when the layout get loaded it dont have submit button. It will only be visible on oncheck a check box.

Comment: Please then reorginise your question. It is not clear what you want. Views can be dynamically added by ie: relativeParent.addView(textView); And don't forget to set layout parameters such as width and height.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code to add view dynamically. Call this method `onCheckChangeListener`. Replace `TextView` from `Button` and set your parameters accordingly.

```
private TextView addTextView(){
    TextView txtToBeAdded = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    txtToBeAdded.setText("Tap to\nadd More");
    txtToBeAdded.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMarginStart((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 5, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
    txtToBeAdded.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    txtToBeAdded.setClickable(true);
    txtToBeAdded.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    txtToBeAdded.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectPicture(v);
        }
    });
    return txtToBeAdded;
}
```

Get reference to the parent and call `parent.addView(addTextView)`
May be it is helpful

### **EDIT**

Match this with your code

```
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    CheckBox txtListChild = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams firstParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 150);
    //Button h = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button999) ;
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int color = Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255);
    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    txtListChild.setLayoutParams(firstParam);
    txtListChild.setBackgroundColor(color);
    txtListChild.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
            if(arg1)
                linearLayout.addView(addButton());
        }
    } 
   return convertView;
}

private Button addButton(){
    Button btnToBeAdded = new Button(getContext());
    btnToBeAdded.setText("YourText");
    btnToBeAdded.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    btnToBeAdded.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    btnToBeAdded.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    btnToBeAdded.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //perform button click
        }
    });
    return btnToBeAdded;
}
```

Give your LinearLayout id and remove button tag.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100">
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New CheckBox"
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can u pls tell me how to get the parent reference from code which i have posted in the questions

Comment: Your parent here is `LinearLayout`. Give it an id (`android:id="@+id/linearLayout"`. Then in your activity `LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout)`. Then add your view in it. `linearLayout.addView(addTextView)`

Comment: Will it work with  LayoutInflater infalInflater  since i m using exapandable list i tried this but button is not coming

Comment: Use `convertView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout)` and add view inside `onCheckChanged`

Comment: convertView is not final and getting compilation exception as i have to declare it as final in Expandable list view adaptor. convertView is variable which is getting passed in method to get getChildView

Answer (score 0):

You can change the visibility of the button in your onCheckChangeListener.

First in your xml layout, define a button with the visibility set as gone :

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="submit"/>
```

Then in your activity find the button first

```
Private Button button;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    CheckBox txtListChild = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    txtListChild.setLayoutParams(firstParam);
    txtListChild.setBackgroundColor(color);
    txtListChild.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
          if (arg1) {
            button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }
          else {
            button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          }
       }
 }
```

Comment: its not working do i need to add it in view object to make it visible i am using     LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

Comment: if the check box is within the list item layout and the button is within the activity then you need to create a callback from the adapter to the activity. Display your adapter and your activity so I can help you precisely.